# Thought I knew what this was

Tags: angular, scope, instance-variables

In the code snippet below, I am using a service (Angular) to extract text via a fileReader, using a promise for the async part. The issue I'm having is (I believe) a scope issue and am confused by it. In my component, I declare an instance variable:
myDoc : docWrapperClass.

Basically when the file reader extracts the text, I want to assign the results to this local variable. Everything works well until I try to do the assignment. i.e.: 
this.myDoc = docContents  when the promise resolves (Currently comment out).

When the statement is left in the compiler complains:
Type '{}' is not assignable to type docWrapperClass: fileName.

There is a property on the docWrapperClass called fileName, but not sure what the {} means. I have commented out the assignment, and then put a breakpoint on the console.log statement in the then() block. When I type 
"this" in the  console, I get undefined, which REALLY confuses me. I would at least expect "this" to a function. My question is how do I assign the docWrapperClass returned from the promise, to the instance variable?

```
export class myDocComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private fileReaderService: ReadLocalFileService,
    private textExtractor: TextExtractorServiceService) { }

ngOnInit() { }

docWords: string[] = [];
myDoc: docWrapperClass = null;

selectFile(event: any) {
    console.log("Debug");
    this.fileReaderService.readFile(event.target.files)
    .then((docContents) => {
        console.log("DocContents: " + docContents);
        //this.myDoc = docContents;
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is the function signature of `this.fileReaderService.readFile` ?

Comment: public readFile(files: FileList) {} Note this is working fine, and when I breakpoint in the then() block I can see the results, I just can't seem to assign them to the instance variable.

Comment: The assignment should work if you force `readFile` to return a `Promise<docWrapperClass>`.

Comment: That makes sense, let me go try!

Comment: Works! Thanks so much, not sure how long I would have spent before that occurred to me.

Comment: Also, you're losing the `this` scope because of the Promise callback, a common JS pain. You can bind a lexical `this` that will always refer to the component by declaring the method as a lambda, i.e. `selectFile = (event: any) => {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.fileReaderService.readFile` doesn't have a return signature, so when you call `then` on it's returned value, the Typescript compiler has no idea what it's working with. Therefore, your `docContents` is of type `{}`, which is not assignable to your type `docWrapperClass`.

One of the big advantages of TypeScript in the first place is type safety. You should define the return type of `readFile` to be `Promise<docWrapperClass>`, and likewise define the return type of all of your functions.

Once the compiler is aware that the method returns a `Promise<docWrapperClass`, it can properly infer that `docContents` is assignable to `myDoc`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. My original implementation did just that, but I stripped it down for troubleshooting, and created a different problem! Everything is working and appreciate the help.